# How to make JavaScript's test return false if at least one of the forbidden characters is present?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want test to return false if at least one of the following characters are present: `^/,:<>!_~@#$%^&()+=?()“|!\[#$-`

So I did this:

```
const pattern = /[^/,:<>!_~@#$%^&()+=?()“|!\[#$-]/
console.log(pattern.test('fff>'))
```

However this returns `true`
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/alexcheninfo/pen/RpYvXo)

It should return false because there's at least one of the forbidden characters: `<`.

How to modify the regex to reflect that?

Comment: Use a negative lookahead: `(^?!.*[allofyourcharacters here])`

Comment: It should return *true*, because part of the pattern matched. "**true if there is a match**" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the start with `^` and end with `$` and add a plus to the class `+`

Otherwise,

It matches `fff` and so return true.

If you strict start and end, then it will perform a full test.

```js
const pattern = /^[^/,:<>!_~@#$%^&()+=?()“|!\[#$-]+$/;
console.log(pattern.test('fff>')); // false
console.log(pattern.test('fff')); // true
```

Comment: Fairly certain the `^` character itself is also supposed to be in the list of forbidden chars. So you'll need to add that into the negated class. But this should work otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, you may want to use a negative lookahead:

```js
const pattern = /(?!.*[/^,:<>!_~@#$%^&()+=?()“|!\[#$-]).+/
console.log(pattern.test('fff>'))
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/qCVlCn/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Why would you check for forbidden characters with a negated character class?

Use a regular character class and things become straight-forward.

```
const forbiddenChars = /[/,:<>!_~@#$%^&()+=?()“|!\[#$-]/;
var success = !inputString.test(forbiddenChars);
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex pattern appears to contain numerous non-escaped special characters, and duplicated characters. Assuming the intent was to detect the presence of any of the listed special characters, this should achieve the desired result:

```
const pattern = /[\\\/,:<>!_~@#$%\^&()\+=\?"\|\[\]-]/;
console.log( ! pattern.test('fff>');
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally do my test to check if special characters exist and then negate that. So if a special exist should return false.
You will need to escape the followong characters:
open/close square brackets, "[" and "]"; the backslash "\"; the caret "^"; the dollar sign "$"; the period or dot "."; the vertical bar or pipe symbol "|"; the question mark "?"; the asterisk "*"; the plus/minus-sign "+"/"-"; open/close curly braces, "{" and "}"; and open/close parenthesis, "(" and ")"

`const pattern = /[/,:<>!_~@#\$%\^&\(\)\+=\?"\|!\\\[#$\-\]]/
console.log(!pattern.test('fff>'))`

try this pattern. Remember pattern is to find special characters dont forget to negate the result. Unfortunately im unable to test atm. Im using mobile device. I'll edit later if i do test.

**Note**: not sure if i escaped all the meta characters.

**Note 2**: not sure if dont want "*" to be accepted if thats not the case add "*" to the regex. add it somewhere in the middle

**Note 3**: also the double in your expression test seems to be different to the double quote produced using my keyboard. normally when i use word processor i get a tilted double quote like you have. if you want to include the normal quote here it is ("). if did mean the tilted quote you will also need the close tilted quote, unfortunately i am unable to reproduce it.
**Note 3 - updated**: have edited the regex to test for the normal double quotes.

**EDITED** - I have tested it seems to be working.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RpYdmM?editors=1111
I havent tried all the special characters. only a few. take a look